# JQ pull value from key searched by related key

Tags: json, jq

Im bashing my head against a wall - aim pull value from key searched by related

JSON SNIPPIT

```
{
  "block": {
    "000545342981": [
      {
        "CODE": "xdxd3456532fok234sss0"
      },
      {
        "STATE": "COMPLETE"
      }
    ],
   "000545341211": [
      {
        "CODE": "xdff3678223frt244swe4"
      },
      {
        "STATE": "RUNNING"
      }
    ]
}}
```

I wish to retrieve the `CODE` value for each ACCOUNT

ie for
`000545342981` i wish to have `xdxd3456532fok234sss0` returned and
`xdff3678223frt244swe4` for `000545341211`

then place in bash as

```
accounts+=(
["000545342981"]=xdxd3456532fok234sss0
["000545341211"]=xdff3678223frt244swe4
)
```

SO FAR
i have returned the accounts with
`jq --slurp '.?|.[][]|keys' | jq -r '.[]'`

then i tried `jq --arg code "ACCOUNT" 'select ( ."block".key==$code) | ."block".$stack."CODE"'` ----> no errors :/ so suspect it may not of found anything

this will kind of work `."block"."000545341211"[]."CODE"`
but i know i cant input a var in jq from a for each so need arg input (unless im very wrong)
its the `select ( ."block".key==$code)` i think?? what do i need :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If each account contains only one code, you can do :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

declare -A accounts
while read account code; do
    accounts[$account]=$code
done < <(jq -r '.block       |
                to_entries[] |
                "\(.key) \(.value[0].CODE)"' input.json)
declare -p accounts
```

Comment: you are a savior